# xml attribute not well-formed?

Tags: xml

Simple question. If I attempt to look at

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<test key="blah('foo=1&bar=2')">
</test>
```

in Firefox, it complains

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: file:///C:/tmp/dump2.xml
Line Number 2, Column 27:

<test key="blah('foo=1&bar=2')">
--------------------------^
```

Why is this? What do I need to escape?

Comment: I bet if you start removing one character at a time until it doesn't complain anymore you'll have the answer yourself before you get the answer here.

Comment: sigh. the -1'er is at it again. You know, not everyone is omniscient enough to think of all the so-called obvious solutions in a short period of time.

Comment: I didn't downvote. I thought it was a well-written question you should already have known the answer to, or that you should have figured it out yourself before posting, but that's not a reason for a downvote.

Comment: @John: Yeah, I thought I should have already known the answer to it too, or that I would have been able to figure it out myself quickly. I didn't -- for some reason I thought double-quoted attributes allowed anything except a double-quote inside. That's why I posted here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<test key="blah('foo=1&bar=2')">
</test>
```

is not well-formed XML. Use:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<test key="blah('foo=1&amp;bar=2')">
</test>
```

**EDIT:**

Error message in Oxygen XML Editor:

> F [Xerces] The reference to entity
>   "bar" must end with the ';' delimiter.

That means `&bar` is parsed as [*entity reference*](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-EntityRef), but here is syntax error, that is, missing `;`. You need to [escape](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-escape) `&` character using predefined entity (one of five) `&amp;`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use entity codes for ampersand and apostrophe

```
&amp; 
&apos;
```

See [this site](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)

Answer (score 1):

Change the ampersand & to &amp;

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the ampersand was the problem; this works fine:

```
<test key="blah('foo=1&amp;bar=2')">
```

Where's the writeup on needing to escape ampersands in attributes?

Comment: @John: thanks! I've been googling "xml attribute ampersand" for the past 5 minutes and couldn't find that or any references to it. Post as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: You're really showing a lot of unwillingness to do the most elementary homework.  http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006#syntax, or w3schools, or any hundreds of other resources, or google, or...

Comment: @Jason: your google may have failed because it has nothing to do with attributes. Notice where that is within the XML spec.

Comment: @Ed: >:P >:P >:P You are WAY quick to judge how much effort I put into this. I've been spending the past 15 minutes trying to solve this problem. I *do* know how to google, and apparently I missed the combination of search phrases to pop up the answer.

Comment: @Jason: Sorry, you're right.  As John said, the "attribute" threw you into a dark hole.